# How to update docker image over slow connection

Tags: docker, rsync

We have our application in a docker, size is about 600mb. One of our customers has slow and unreliable internet connection so transfering image updates of that size is not feasible. Also there are reasons why Docker Registry is not an option for updates.

I wonder if it is a way to somehow transfer only the difference between our latest image and customer's image.

We could either use clean CI/CD image with no additional layers or we could make a `COPY` layer ourselves with the files changed (although it is not handy).

I already tried using `rsync` over `docker save` tar archive. Neither clean CI/CD image nor layered image transfer produced a good result. Say I updated image by 1mb and the `rsync` download size was 200+mb anyway.

So the question is can we transfer differences between customer's image and clean CI/CD latest version of an image or meybe somehow transfer only that `COPY` layer using another approach?

Comment: This gets asked very occasionally ([How docker load a diff image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63547629/how-docker-load-a-diff-image), [Is there a clever way to do this with Docker (maybe via save/load/diff)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31040045/is-there-a-clever-way-to-do-this-with-docker-maybe-via-save-load-diff)) and I still don't believe there is a way to transfer only diffs or individual layers using the `docker save` tool set.